# Prisma constraint not available

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I`m using Prisma with NestJS and PostgreSQL

In my schema.prisma i have this

```
model User {
  userId       Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  firstName    String?  @db.VarChar(25)
  lastName     String?  @db.VarChar(25)
  login        String   @unique @db.VarChar(60)
  email        String   @unique
  password     String   
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
  role         Role?    @default(ADMIN)
  createdUsers User[]   @relation("createdBy")
  createdBy    User?    @relation("createdBy", fields: [creatorId], references: [userId])
  creatorId    Int?
}

enum Role {
  ADMIN
  MANAGER
  WAREHOUSE
  USER
}
```

So when a make create request like this

```
{
login: "A",
email: "A",
password: "A"
}
```

it saves in DB - that`s ok. By after the same request i get this error "Unique constraint failed on the (not available)". So **shouldn't there be a not unique column** name **instead of (not available)** or that is ok case? Where am i wrong?

I was trying drop table Users and make different unique combs, don`t know what else i can do...

UPD:

```
async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
 return this.prisma.user.create({
  data: {
   ...createUserDto
  }
 })
}

    export class CreateUserDto {
        @IsNotEmpty()
        login: string;
      
        @IsNotEmpty()
        @IsEmail()
        email: string;
    
        @IsNotEmpty()
        @MinLength(6)
        password: string;
    }
```

UPD 2.0
Finally, moved to TypeORM, it is bug like @num8er mentioned
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10829

Ty for all the replies

Comment: I think you are wrong on the unique password. Email sure should be unique, so no duplicated users are allowed but password as it is supposed to be secret you can't guarantee that user a and b are or are not using the same password.

Comment: Sure, you right. Edited my answer. login and email unique.

Comment: So in this case no, you are not wrong. It is expected that a system would not allow two users with the same identifications. So if you are trying to use the same request to save a user and it is returning an error that is the correct thing to do. What you need to do is to handle it gracefully and show a message to the user saying like: "This login and email already exist in our system".

Comment: if login and/or email is unique, so make Your another request to not have same email and login.

Comment: update Your question and add how You create user from controller perspective calling model

Comment: I updated the question. In general, my question is whether it is normal that prisma does not return a non-unique field that i trying to pass, but instead writes "not available"

Comment: I've read manual about prisma and nestjs integration: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma  which has examples where I don't see that they use DTO-s, which means that You have to convert DTO-s to plain object or do like: `data: {email: createUserDto.email, login: createUserDto.login, password: createUserDto.password}`   try it and if it will work then write transformer function to convert DTO-s to plain objects.

Comment: same error with plain object

Comment: looks like bug on prisma still not solved: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10829

Comment: I suspect that You have not defined id field - replace userId with id.

Comment: also try to directly insert to db, see if autoincrement work on postgres level.